# show & post different value in HTML <input list> Attribute

Tags: html

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">IE
    <option value="Firefox">FR
    <option value="Chrome">Ch
    <option value="Opera">Op
    <option value="Safari">Safari
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to see IE,FR.Ch in dropdown & post the value like Internet Explorer,Firefox,etc but dropdown & post both value are same.How can i do it?

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">IE</option>
    <option value="Firefox">FR</option>
    <option value="Chrome">CH</option>
    <option value="Opera">OP</option>
    <option value="Safari">SF</option>
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Close the `option` tags! E.g. `<option value="Internet Explorer">IE</option>`

Comment: but dropdown is showing both Internet Explorer & IE side by side.I want only IE in dropdown.

Comment: Yeah just close the `option` tag after the name. (With `</option>`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
 <input list="browsers" name="browser">
 <datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">IE</option>
  <option value="Firefox">FR</option>
  <option value="Chrome1">Ch</option>
  <option value="Opera2">Op</option>
  <option value="Safari3">Safari</option>
 </datalist>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```